# ping , copy , restart is it possible ina cron

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron

I've had some troubles on my server lately , am not familiar with linux much , but i usually do these steps when i brick my server trying to follow a tutorial to install openvpn ...

anyway , i do the following :

```
ping google.com
```

if it does not ping

```
cp /etc/network/interfaces-backup /etc/network/interfaces
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

is there anyway to add this to cron ?

Thank you

Comment: Does stopping the openvpn service restore the original networking configuration?

Comment: nope , its dead even before starting the openvpn , due to bridging misconfiguration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, but to better understand the causes of the problem.

Create script:

```
# touch /usr/local/sbin/check_openvpn
# chmod +x /usr/local/sbin/check_openvpn
```

/usr/local/sbin/check_openvpn:

```
#!/bin/bash

/bin/ping -c 3 google.com  || (cp /etc/network/interfaces-backup /etc/network/interfaces; /etc/init.d/networking restart)
```

Add to root crontab(every 5 minute):

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/sbin/check_openvpn
```

Comment: you don't need sudo if it's gonna be in roots crontab.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you could add this to cron, but I think you better should find what is causing your problems. Why does your interfaces configuration get messed up?

If the ping does not owrk, what do you get as an error message? Network unreachable? Or can't the name google.com be resolved, no IP address showing?

What are the contents of /etc/resolv.conf when it works and when it does not?

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
```

And the default gateway also in bot cases?

```
route -n
```

How do you connect to the internet? Through a router? WiFi?

You should try to find out why this is happening. Many people here will help you, but need more info about your connection or what you are doing, when do the settings change and the connection stops working?

Comment: My server is in a datacenter , i lost connection to it when trying to do bridging for the openvpn :( , i had to pay for a KVM to restore that file , i followed the steps in openvpn howto page , when i run the start shell script i lost connection .